# New OneDrive Sycn will support IRM files sync

Tags: office-365, onedrive-for-business, onedrive

Will new next generation sync will support IRM sync file? New sync file is called as "onedrive.exe" . I know that old sync tool will support IRM (groove.exe).

Answer: Old sync tool will support IRM enabled files.

New sync tool won't support IRM enabled files which is a big drawback for my organization. You can find the limitations under this URL.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3125202/restrictions-and-limitations-when-you-sync-files-and-folders